# Fetching data from other aggregate (Domain Driven Design)

Tags: domain-driven-design, event-sourcing

In our domain, AggregateA needs to access data from multiple other aggregates. As far as I know, I can not directly reach Root of other aggregates.

In this case, what is the practical way of getting the data for AggregateA?

- Build a middle layer Repository and persist data needed by AggregateA?
- Use domain events to ask for data from other aggregates?

[image]

Comment: Do you mean you need to "query" Aggregate A data along with data from B and C? Or does business logic in Aggregate A need data from B and C?

Comment: Business logic in Aggregate A needs data from B and C. But those data can not be broadcasted by simple events.

Answer (score 0):

Business logic in one agg can never depend on state from another agg, so if that is the case you may need to redesign your aggregate boundaries. But depending on your project it may be easier to "lift" your tx-boundary from what you call "aggregate" and assign it to a larger scope.